# Unable to save string to file in external SD card using fragments in android java 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

Objective :The project reads bluetooth data and should save to the file. I have 2 fragments , Setting fragment and DataDisplay fragment. There are 2 buttons in setting fragment. One is for creating file using document tree. Other is Write button, after clicking on Write button, it should create file using uristring returned from CreateDocument button and save the data on every DataChange in DataDisplay fragment.
I am able to get URI from Setting fragment and save it in DataDisplay fragment. But using same uristring I am unable to create file and save data to the same file selected by user. Permissions given to file.

Error : I always get an error as file doesn't exists.

Please suggest me on this. Following is the code snippet.

```
Code : 
Setting fragment 
  @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mCommunication = (SenderFragmentListener) context;
        mCommunicationwrite=(SenderFragmentListenerwrite) context;
    }
  private void writeclickfun(Context context) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"In WriteClickfun",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mCommunicationwrite.messageFromSenderFragmentwrite(1);

    }

  @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                              Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
                settingFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false);
    Button activity_externalstorage_write = (Button) settingFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.activity_externalstorage_write);
// perform setOnClickListener on second Button
        activity_externalstorage_write.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// display a message by using a Toast
                Toast.makeText(settingFragmentView.getContext(), "Button Write", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                writeclickfun(settingFragmentView.getContext());
               // writebuttonclickupdate(1);
            }
        });
        return settingFragmentView;
    }
 public interface SenderFragmentListenerwrite {
        void messageFromSenderFragmentwrite(int startwrite);
    }

Data Display Fragment : 

 private void writeTextData(File file, String data) throws IOException {
       //f Toast.makeText(myFragView.getContext(),"Inside WriteTextData File :"+ file,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               //  fileOutputStream.write(data.getBytes());
   // Toast.makeText(myFragView.getContext(),"Before : "  + data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if((MainActivity.uristring != null) && MainActivity.fileexistsflag == 0)
        {
            MainActivity.file = new File(String.valueOf(Uri.parse(MainActivity.uristring)));
            Toast.makeText(myFragView.getContext(),"File Created writeTextData: "+MainActivity.file,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(MainActivity.file.exists() == true)
            {
                MainActivity.fileexistsflag = 1;
            }
        }
        if(MainActivity.file.exists() == true) {
            Toast.makeText(myFragView.getContext(),"After File created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
            //  Toast.makeText(myFragView.getContext(),"Inside WriteTextData fileoutputstream File :"+ fileOutputStream,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            fileOutputStream.write(data.getBytes());
            Toast.makeText(myFragView.getContext(),"After Writing data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Toast.makeText(myFragView.getContext(),"Inside WriteTextData After write",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
              Toast.makeText(myFragView.getContext(),"Inside WriteTextData File doesn't exists ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}

 public void  FileLoggermessage(View v, String aLogMessage) throws IOException {
        Log.e("FileLogger","Inside File Logger");
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        Log.e("FileLogger", String.valueOf(now));
        String Final_Message= now + "," + aLogMessage + "";
                writeTextData(MainActivity.file, Final_Message);
}

  @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                              Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        myFragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data_display, container, false);

        return myFragView;
    }

    public void youGotMsgstartwrite(int startwrite) {
        // tv_msg.setText(msg);
        Log.e("File write","Inside youGotMsgstartwrite in Data Display" + startwrite);
        MainActivity.startwritedata=startwrite;

        Toast.makeText(myFragView.getContext(), "Start write in data display youGotMsgstartwrite:" + startwrite, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(myFragView.getContext(), "Start write in data display youGotMsgstartwritedata:" + MainActivity.startwritedata, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void onDataChage(String myNtificationData) throws IOException {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // DataDisplayFragment context;
            if(MainActivity.startwritedata == 1) {
                FileLoggermessage(myBatteryPercentageView, myNtificationData);
            }
        }
}

Main Activity : 
  @Override
    public void onAttachFragment( Fragment fragment ) {
        if (fragment instanceof SettingFragment) {
            SettingFragment headlinesFragment = (SettingFragment) fragment;
            headlinesFragment.setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(this);
        }
        if (fragment instanceof DataDisplayFragment) {
            DataDisplayFragment dataDisplay = (DataDisplayFragment) fragment;
            dataDisplay.setonDisplayFragmentPause(this);
        }
    }
 @Override
    public void messageFromSenderFragmentwrite(int startwrite){

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        DataDisplayFragment mReceiverFragmentwrite = (DataDisplayFragment)manager.findFragmentById(R.id.frg_Sender);
        mReceiverFragmentwrite.youGotMsgstartwrite(startwrite);
    }
```

Comment: `after clicking on Write button, it should create file using uristring returned from CreateDocument button` The file was already created using the first button. So how can it be created again?

Comment: `MainActivity.file = new File(String.valueOf(Uri.parse(MainActivity.uristring)))` One cannot use the File class for a saf uri string.

Comment: ok. Then how to access the file in DataDisplay fragment which was created in setting fragment.